# Type 'Response' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' \ 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, codable

```
class ErrorObj: NSObject,Codable {
    var numError:Int = 0
    var DescriptionError = ""
}

class Response<T: Codable>: NSObject, Codable { 
    var error:ErrorObj!
    var result:T!
    
    
    func getResponse(errorObj:(ErrorObj)->Void,sucssesObj:(T)->Void) {
        if error.numError != 0 {
            errorObj(error)
        } else{
            sucssesObj(result)
        }
    }
    
}
```

errors:

> Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'T?' does not conform to 'Decodable'
> Protocol requires initializer 'init(from:)' with type 'Decodable'

> Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'T?' does not conform to 'Encodable'
> Protocol requires initializer 'init(from:)' with type 'Encodable'

Comment: You need to make `ErrorObj` also conform to `Codable`.

Comment: tnk for your comment ,
this my class ErrorObj
</br>
```class ErrorObj: NSObject,Codable {

    var numError:Int = 0
    var DescriptionError = ""
    
    
}```
</br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that you declared both properties of `Response` as implicitly unwrapped optionals (IOU). The compiler cannot autogenerate the required methods of `Codable` for IOU properties.

However, there's no need to make those IOU anyways. If they are required properties that are always present in the response, make them non-optional. If they might be missing, make them `Optional` (use `?` instead of `!`).

Also, Swift is not Objective-C. There's no need to make your types inherit from `NSObject`. And you should also use `struct`s instead of `class`es unless you explicitly need reference type behaviour. You should also make all properties immutable unless you explicitly need to be able to mutate them.

```
struct ErrorObj: Codable {
    let numError: Int
    let description: String
}

struct Response<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let error: ErrorObj
    let result: T

    func getResponse(errorObj: (ErrorObj) -> Void, successObj: (T) -> Void) {
        if error.numError != 0 {
            errorObj(error)
        } else{
            successObj(result)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it is help me!!, tnk u very much!